# Error in R when creating a histogram "invalid number of 'breaks'"

Tags: r

Relatively new to R and RStudio, need to test a hypothesis for my Remote Sensing project. 
A bit of context: testing the slope of forest loss in 2 different protected areas in the Congo Basin, so doing a bit of work in ArcMap too. 
When using some code (see below), a histogram for one of the areas looks just fine, but when creating a histogram for another area, R pops up with an "invalid number of 'breaks'" error. I can't seem to figure it out, so any help or suggestions is appreciated. Thanks!

The code I'm using is this:

```
# Open the .tif file for each protected area's forest loss once you specify 
# the filename correctly
tifSankuruNR<-raster("..." )
tifVirungaNP<-raster("...")

# Extract just the numeric values from the rasters
valuesSankuruNR<-values(tifSankuruNR) 
valuesVirungaNP<-values(tifVirungaNP) 

# Create a histogram of the values in the rasters
hist(valuesSankuruNR)
hist(valuesVirungaNP)
```

Sankuru and Virunga are two of the protected areas I'm investigating and NR = Nature Reserve, whilst NP= National Park

```
**Edit**
**tifSankuruNR<-raster("SankuruForestLoss.tif")**

**tifVirungaNP<-raster("VirungaForestLoss.tif")**
```

Comment: It's not easy to help without [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of the data. Can put `dput` part of the data?

Comment: @svenhalvorson I'm not quite sure what you mean, I'm running the code based on .tif files from ArcMap!

Comment: Arina, do we have those .tif files?

Comment: @r2evans yes! I have those .tif files, let me try and put them into the question

Comment: Maybe if you `dput(valuesVirungaNP)`, or the actual data that is giving the error in the `hist` command.